# Installing Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: boot, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu in my laptop. I own a Toshiba Satellite C650. This model is not mentioned in Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware section. Would my laptop still be run Ubuntu along with Windows 8.1 and would double booting erase any of my drivers?

Comment: It will not erase any drivers. We do not know what is that laptop. But if it supports Win 8, it should support Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Try Ubuntu Mate for best user experience. https://ubuntu-mate.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Desktop edition [requires](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) (I cite the 2 main elements):

1. 700 MHz processor
2. 512 MiB RAM

[Toshiba Satellite C650](http://www.cnet.com/au/products/toshiba-satellite-c650/) fulfills these requirements *largely*. So yes, you can install Ubuntu on it. And since you run Windows 8.1, surely you can run Ubuntu too on it.

For your second question, the simple answer is no, your pre-installed system won't be erased: you can install Ubuntu alongside your Windows OS. That is discussed through many interesting posts here such as [here](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=ubuntu%20alonside%20windows) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot).